# Discord.py There is a way to change the status of a bot?

Tags: discord.py

```
game = discord.Game("Testing")
await client.change_presence(activity=game)
```

This is the coee, but I get as status "Playing Testing" and not "Testing". There is a way to only show Testing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bots cannot currently set custom statuses, which is the only way to not have a prefix such as "playing", "watching", etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you playing some games, you can see in your activity: playing (something).
If you want have only testing, adjust status.